# How to control hair particle position?

Tags: particles

I am trying to make some grass. I want to have grass only near the edges of my plane and not on the center.

Is any way to do that?

Or I have to split the plane and make different objects?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Vertex Weights:

You can use [*Vertex Groups*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Vertex_Groups).

1. Subdivide your plane (<kbd>W</kbd>*> Subdivide*)

   [image]
2. Deselect the middle with Circle select (<kbd>C</kbd>) and use <kbd>MMB</kbd> to deselect (or hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and use <kbd>LMB</kbd>)

   [image]
3. Add a vertex group and click *Assign* in *Properties > Object data > Vertex Groups*:

   [image]
4. Select the vertex group in *Properties > Particles > Vertex Groups*:

   [image]

## Textures:

You can also use a *Particle Texture*. This does not require that you subdivide your mesh.

1. Add a particle texture to your object by clicking *New* in *Properties > Particle system > Textures*. Then switch to the texture tab.
2. Ensure that the the datablock type is set to *Particle system*.
3. Set the texture type to *Blend*
4. Set the *Progression* to *Sphere*
5. Enable *Density* in the *Influence* section so the texture influences the density of the particles.
6. Enable *Ramp* to control the texture with a color ramp.
7. Flip the ramp and adjust the stops so the particles are correctly placed.

[image]

Comment: Vertex weight can be painted to have more than binary values. Instead of just on/off you can have all values between 0 and 1. This way you can have patches with less grass, but not completely empty.

Comment: @Gunslinger Quite right. You can also use it to affect the length and other properties, so the grass gets shorter towards the edges etc.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answer. You can also do Ctrl+Shift to go into weight painting mode and then paint on a heat map, the parts you paint red will be the parts that will have hair particles on the mesh.

Don't forget to set group as the density for the particle system.[image]enter image description here
[image]