# is it possible (if so, how) to use a part of a material applied to a mesh as emitter?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, shaders

I'm making a material (cycles) for a mountain :

[image]

I would like to add some grass (hair) in the green zone. Is it possible (if so, how) to do that by using the green part ?

Comment: Not using cycles textures, but you can do this with BI procedural textures.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6250/599

Comment: @gandlaf3 your link isn't related to my problem. I want to avoid to make a vertex group by hand to save time

Comment: I know vertex weights aren't optimal, but I think you might be able to bake your cycles texture to an image texture and use that as a particle map (the linked question also shows how to use textures).