# Vertex Groups Density working in opposite way

Tags: particles, vertex-groups

I'm learning how to add hair with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Bo3wmQ5qLU

I've followed the path slowly and I got to the point of assigning density = my group of selected area almost the same way it is explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/how-to-control-hair-particle-position)

However, the result I get is the opposite of what I want.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have clicked the inverse ( the double headed arrow on the right of the density ) just click it again

Comment: @Chebhou Should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @RayMairlot I'm writing just a minute

Comment: This is embarrasing I didn't even knew that there was a button right there, just lost 2 hours of my life trying to solve it...Please post an answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have clicked the inverse button , just click it again and it will go back to normal :

[image]