# If I'm using hair particles for grass using groups, how can I create dead spots?

Tags: particles

By dead spots I mean places where grass won't grow on my plane e.g. for walkways. I've been wondering this for a while but I haven't seen anything in regards to it online. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6250/599

Comment: @TLousky you gave a link to the same answer gandalf3 suggested as a duplicate :).

Comment: Hah! Silly me, deleted it.

Comment: Yeah turns out I wasn't using the correct words when searching. Hard to search when you aren't aware of the lingo! Thanks for the help and sorry for the duplicate post!