# Is there any way to Delete Particles separately?

Tags: particles

I am working on my renders and using Hair Type Particle System.

Particles are applied on some of the places where I don't want them , So is there any way to delete particles separately without affecting whole particle system configuration ?

I tried Individual selecting those particles and deleting them but whole group is deleting.

Comment: Two ways - controlling with [weights / textures](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/how-to-control-hair-particle-position) or applying Particle System modifier (warning: no flexibility) and then deleting manually.

Comment: You need to use [particle edit mode](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/mode.html) to select and delete single hairs that you don't want.