# Matching Surface Indentations with Particle System (Dandelion seed particles on head)

Tags: modeling, particles

I'm creating a dandelion model in blender. So far I've created a single dandelion seed which I intend to instance/duplicate as perhaps particles and spread them over the surface of the head of the dandelion stalk. Is there a way to create surface indentations on the head that match where the seeds are, like in the image below?
[image]

Comment: It can be done with particle system settings - either vertex group controlling density (amount of vertices of the emitter and topology have to allow that i.e. be dense) or a texture driving particles density (object has to be unwrapped). Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/how-to-control-hair-particle-position

Comment: You could also use a separate dummy mesh solely for the purpose of being an emitter for the particles, with such topology that its vertex perfectly match those indents on the renderably center