# Lot of small holes in a sphere / round shape for game

Tags: modeling

I need to model sth like this

[image]

but with like 3-4x holes. Will be used in an VR app, so I have to take a look at the poly count.

I was wondering if there is a more effective way of doing this than just cutting every hole in tha sphere (which is crazy difficult for a newbie like me?).

Can I cut the holes maybe in the texture or use some modifier to accelerate the process?

I've found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2OKfslc7As&t=17s), which create a crazy amount of polygons.

And [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAJjzZQ807M), but here can't find the way to make a closed sphere instead of a tube

Comment: How detailed does the model need to be and how many polygons is too much?

Comment: too much polys woulg be more than 1k (I think). The VR app is a showroom, there will not be a lot of stuff in the scene, I will keep it simple, since I need to have detailed products. It should be detailed enough to notice what it is, but it is decoration and not an important product.

Comment: This could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88445/repeating-hole-pattern-or-texture-on-surfaces-climbing-wall-drill-holes/88493#88493

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use textures. Unless the player is going to be interacting with the holes in some meaningful way, they are just decoration and do not need to be modelled.

The texture could either use transparency, or just set the color to black and specularity to zero.