# How to scatter several rocks along a path?

Tags: particles

I've been following Blender Guru's tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EesfCLQD8jY) on how to create a martian landscape, but I want the rocks to scatter on just one part of the surface using a particle system.  Is there a way to do this?

This is the area I'm talking about:

[image]

These are the particle settings (for one set of rocks)

[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/how-to-control-hair-particle-position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You want to create a vertex group and put that in for particle density.

Long Answer:
If you assign the particle emission to to the land you'll get something like this:[image]

Obviously we don't want the icospheres all over the plane, just a select portion. We can do this we two methods, weight pain or creating a vertex group. Weight pain will give you more control, but I'll show how to assign a vertex group because it's a little bit quicker.

So tab into edit mode. Hit "c" and paint the vertices you wish to be affected.[image]

Now invert the selection with Ctrl "i" and go to vertex groups on the right and assign a group. [image]
Now go back to the particle system, scroll down to vertex groups and select the group. I would recommend naming the group. 
[image]

Comment: Nice!  That worked very well!  I also tried the weight paint mode which like you said gave more flexibility